# destroyItem function of PageAdapter is not being called when any view is removed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am working on an android application and using viewpager in a view. I am using PagerAdapter to show the views of tabs in viewpager.
I have to add/remove some Tabs dynamically. When I am adding any tab along with it's view then **instantiateItem** function is being called and tab is getting added successfully. But When I remove any tab from viewpager then **destroyItem** function should be called but it is not getting called and the view of Tab is not getting removed. 
This the code which I am using to add/remove tabs.

```
public List<View> viewsList = new ArrayList();
public HashMap<Integer, View> GridViewList = new HashMap<>();

MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(myAdapter.getCount() + 1);

    private class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return viewsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View v = viewsList.get(position).rootView;
        container.addView(v, 0);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view) {
        container.removeView((View)view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object key) {
        return key == view;
    }
}
```

I am adding using the below method When I add any Tab along with it's view

```
View view = new View(); // I am making Custom View here
viewsList.add(view);
GridViewList.put(Id, view);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And When I remove any view, I use below method :

```
viewsList.remove(GridViewList.get(Id));
GridViewList.remove(Id);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But the destroyItem function is not being called when I remove any Tab and it's view from adapter in android. Please help me if someone have any idea about this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but: you need to implement `getItemPosition` in order for `destroyItem` to be called.  In this case, something like this *should* work:

```
@Override public int getItemPosition(Object itemIdentifier) {
  int index = viewsList.indexOf(itemIdentifiers);
  return index == -1 ? POSITION_NONE : index;
}
```

Comment: Cheers Eric, it's never too late to join the party.